# getting error trying to use PhoneNumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my attempt to use Ahmed Abdelkader's post on Auto Formatting a Phone Number, i.e., 
http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/auto-formatting-phone-number.html
this, I get:

> "Unknown type name 'PhoneNumberFormatter'; did you mean 'NSNumberFormatter'?"

on the Line:

```
PhoneNumberFormatter* phoneNumberFormatter = [[PhoneNumberFormatter alloc] init];
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you `#import` the .h file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the necessary class implemented or imported in your project.

[This is what you're missing](http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/locale-sensitive-phone-number.html).

Comment: Duh!  I never saw the reference to a full blown objective-c class object!  Thanks so much.